# How to filter json using angular filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, wordpress

Hey i have little problem with angular filter.
I import post from wordpress, and i would really like to filter them by tags, like, now show only post with tag = ENG, or show only post with tag = GER.
This is how my html looks like

```
    <div ng-controller="ThreeMainPosts">
        <div ng-repeat="threePost in threePosts | filter : {data.data.posts[0].tags[0].slug = 'ENG'} ">
            <div three-post="threePost">
                <h1>CONTENT</h1></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller

```
myModule.controller('ThreeMainPosts', function($scope, $location, WordPressNewsService) {
var postsPerPage = 3;
var orderBy = 0;
WordPressNewsService.getPosts(postsPerPage, orderBy).then(function(data) {
    $scope.threePosts = data.data.posts;
});
```

});
and the json

```
    { id: 312, type: "post", slug: "la-bamba-3", url: "sada2", … }
    attachments:[]
    author:{ id: 1, slug: "ds", name: "hnews", first_name: "", last_name: "", … }
    categories:[{ id: 6, slug: "ludzie", title: "Ludzie", description: "", parent: 0, post_count: 2 }]
    tags: [{ id: 32, slug: "en", title: "EN", description: "EN", post_count: 1 }]
    url:"http://xxx0.co,/?p=312"
    previous_url:"http://hirsch-news.iterative.pl/?p=306"
    status:"ok"
```

I tried make the filter in the controller but i can only do this for single element, for example:

```
if(data.data.posts[0].tags[0].slug == "ENG"){
    $scope.threePosts = data.data.posts;
}
```

Any ideas guys?
Have nice day! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Made a quick filter, can change it up to your needs. Hope it helps. [Angular $filter Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Here's a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/tlombrana22/pen/bqyaEp?editors=1010#0) with angular's built in $filter.

```js
myModule
  .controller('ThreeMainPosts', function($scope, $location, WordPressNewsService, $filter) {
    var postsPerPage = 3;
    var orderBy = 0;
    var tagToSortBy = 'EN'
    WordPressNewsService.getPosts(postsPerPage, orderBy).then(function(data) {
      $scope.threePosts = $filter('postFilter')(data.data.posts, tagToSortBy);
    });
  })
  .filter('postFilter', function() {
    return function(post, tag) {
      if (post.tags.slug === tag) {
        return post;
      }
    };
  });
```

If you wanted to do this in the template it would be like this.

```html
<div ng-controller="ThreeMainPosts">
  <div ng-repeat="post in threePosts | postFilter : 'ENG' ">
    <div three-post="threePost">
      <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is the documentation for the Angular $filter. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter This works great for simple filters, but if you need something more complex, you can construct your own filters using angular.module("yourModule").filter().

Comment: @Matt, that's what I did above. a custom filter. just chained it off his controller, didn't want to over-complicate the answer. but thanks for the link will include as an edit for reference.

Comment: Oh, I glanced over this answer quickly. Then another an could be to use Angular's provided filter

Comment: Ohhh god! This works perfect, thanks you so much, you saved many hours of my life :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the `Array.filter` function, in combination with `Array.some`

```
var postsWithTagSlugENG = data.data.posts.filter(function (post) {
    return post.tags.some(function (tag) {
        return tag.slug == "ENG"
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time :). I will just use the code from the guy above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using the filter provided by Angular:

In javascript:

```
$filter('filter')(data.data.posts, tagToSortBy);
```

In HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="searchTag" placeholder="Filter by Any Property" ng-model="search.$" />
<input type="text" name="searchTag" placeholder="Filter by Tag" ng-model="search.tag" />

<div ng-repeat="post in threePosts | filter : search ">
```

The difference between this answer and @alphapilgrim is that you don't have to create your own logic to handle the filtering. Angular provides a base filter that works well in many, if not most situations.

Here are the docs if you would like to learn more about it. It is pretty powerful if you dig deep.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Thanks! i will try it as well :) Have great day.